# error when connect mysql from plesk (GODADDY) with python

Tags: python, mysql, plesk

when i connect with mysql from plesk (godaddy windows hosting) with python an error is occured

**mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '*******:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)**

please help me

````
import mysql.connector

class Db:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host="*******",port=3306, user="", password="", 
       database="")
        self.cur = self.cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)```

    def select(self, q):
        self.cur.execute(q)
        return self.cur.fetchall()


    def selectOne(self, q):
        self.cur.execute(q)
        return self.cur.fetchone()


    def insert(self, q):
        self.cur.execute(q)
        self.cnx.commit()
        return self.cur.lastrowid

    def update(self, q):
        self.cur.execute(q)
        self.cnx.commit()
        return self.cur.rowcount

    def delete(self, q):
        self.cur.execute(q)
        self.cnx.commit()
        return self.cur.rowcount


@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method=='GET':
        db=Db()
        db.select("select * from plusb_customer")
        return render_template("test.html")
    else:
        return "ok"
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to the database on the same machine, change the `hostname` to `localhost`. From the error you're describing, it seems like MySQL is configured not to allow *outside* network connections, so it will only respond to `localhost`.

According to the [GoDaddy Linux Hosting documentation](https://www.godaddy.com/help/view-database-details-for-my-linux-hosting-account-16021):

> #### Related Steps
>
> Applications on your website connect to the database using `localhost` as the host name. Remote connections from your computer use your [hosting account IP address](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-ip-address-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16112). You need to [enable remote connections](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-a-mysql-database-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16103) to use this feature.

Also make sure that the rest of your MySQL connection credentials are correct, like the **username**, **password**, and **database** parameters. It may be helpful to move these details into variables that are clear and at the top level of the module:

```py
MYSQL_HOST = "localhost"
MYSQL_PORT = 3306
MYSQL_USER = "hafis"
MYSQL_PASSWORD = "..."
MYSQL_DATABASE = "example_db"

class Db:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=MYSQL_HOST,
            port=MYSQL_PORT,
            user=MYSQL_USER,
            password=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
            database=MYSQL_DATABASE,
        )
```